# FilteringSelect in Dojo Dialog

Tags: dojo

How to implement the filtering select widget of dojo in dialog .As i have tried below but no luck.if detailed example is shared that will help . i have seen the reference guide but that is not much help.

```
var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
            {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
            {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
            {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
            {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
            {name:"California", id:"CA"},
            {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
            {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
        ]
    });

 

var diaPrdTyp = new dijit.Dialog({
    content: filteringSelect,
    title: "Select Product Type",
    style: "width: 300px; height: 200px;",
    id:"prdtyp"
});

var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "prdtyp");
```

Answer (score 0):

content parameter is for pure text or html. To include a widget, that will be displayed  after content, you can do the following:

```
var diaPrdTyp = new dijit.Dialog({
    content: "Hello world",
    title: "Select Product Type",
    style: "width: 300px; height: 200px;",
    id:"prdtyp"
});
diaPrdTyp.domNode.appendChild(new FilteringSelect(...).domNode);
```